# bootstrap nav-bar collapse icon not triggering

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a simpel nav-bar with bootstrap(i copied from a working template). I've included the latest bootstrap.min.js and an unmodified css from bootwatch.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="z-index:2;">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="../" class="navbar-brand"></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                      <li>
              <a href="../help/">Start</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="../help/">Leverantörer</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

However the button won't trigger the menu when i run it on mobile. What have i done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this JSFIDDLE link. The same code which you shared seems to be working fine.

I  have included the css and JS of bootstrap from CDN.

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="z-index:2;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href="../" class="navbar-brand"></a>

      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li> <a href="../help/">Start</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="../help/">Leverantörer</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/avijitkr/1str8gk6/)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have missed adding the bootstrap.js file.

so just before closing body tag add this line.

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body> > <!-- please note I have added it just before closing body tag -->
```